# MVC, populating form from database data, now need to get data based on model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have a form with an "Add Attendee" button. 
The button calls our service and looks at a database fills in the form based on the database value needs.  Example: Title and Input type.
When "Add Attendee" is also clicked, it adds a new partial view on the main view so that the user can add a new attendee to their list.

Our issue is, now that we submit for our form, we only get ONE of the attendees.  It seems that the form only sees one or the first object.
Are there any examples where there is an "Add Attendee", that dynamically gets created and then on a full form submit, we can submit the collection of attendees with EACH of their information filled in?

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Actual *code* would be immensely helpful. However, I can reasonably guess that you aren't naming your form fields properly, especially if your just dropping in HTML from a partial view each time. In order to bind a list of things, your inputs must be named in the form of:

```
ListProperty[N].Property
```

For example, if your property or action param that accepts a list of attendees was named `Attendees` and each attendee has a `Name` property, then the input on your page for each attendee's name would have to be something like:

```
<input type="text" name="Attendees[0].Name" />
```

If, instead, your input looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" />
```

Then, only the value of the last input on the page with that name will actually be sent.